# Как сделать универсальный шаблон, для передачи указателей на методы

Tags: c++

Я хочу сделать шаблон функции, в который я смогу передавать указатели на методы, в том числе и методы класса.

Но так нельзя:

```
void g_fnc() {};

class tst {
public:
    void fnc() {};
};
template<typename Func>
void SearchFunc(Func * p_func){}

int main()
{
    SearchFunc(&g_fnc);//OK
    SearchFunc(&tst::fnc);//Отсутствуют экземпляры шаблона
}
```

Можно ли сделать шаблон, который будет подходить и под методы-члены классов?

Comment: `::std::function`

Comment: Но как я получу указатель на метод из std::function ?

Comment: Никак не получите, указатель тут и не нужен.

Comment: Но мне нужен указатель на метод, для того чтобы сделать определенные действия с кодом

Comment: ¿И какие действия собираетесь сделать, что они обязательно требуют указателя?

Comment: Нужно дизассемблером пробежаться по функции, рассчитать ее размер до инструкции 'ret' и затереть(это нужно в моем случае).

Comment: Тогда у вас имеется проблема XY - вы пытаетесь что-то намутить с кодом, а спрашиваете про шаблон с адресом (адрес метода даже не является адресом, а даже если бы и являлся, то не обязательно бы являлся адресом кода).

Comment: Не знаю как в других компиляторах, но в моем случае(msvc) адрес метода является соответствующим адресом метода в виртуальной памяти

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите обрабатывать функции-члены класса отдельной (частичной) специализацией шаблона:

```
// Эта специализация будет обрабатывать как указатели на функции, так и указатели на данные
template<typename Func>
void SearchFunc(Func * ptr);

// Это именно указатель на функцию
template<typename Result, typename ... Args >
void SearchFunc(Result  (*ptr)(Args... ) );


// Это указатель на член класса (даные)
template<typename DataType, typename HolderTye >
void SearchFunc(DataType  HolderTye::*ptr );

// Это указатель на функцию - член класса 
template<typename Result, typename HolderTye, typename ... Args >
void SearchFunc(Result  (HolderTye::*ptr) (Args... ) );
```

Однако, никаких гарантий, что передаваемый указатель - суть адрес кода в памяти стандарт не дает.
Указатель на функцию-член класса, не связан ограничениями обратной совместимости с С, поэтому у компилятора развязаны руки.

Более того, он может не совпадать с указателем на данные, даже по размеру:
https://godbolt.org/z/a6WKz1zf1